# Remove newline with re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Why is the result 'bc' and not 'abc'?:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('-\n([a-z])', '','-\nabc',re.M)
'bc'
```

Comment: because `[a-z]` only takes 1 char

Comment: Capturing is useless if you don't put a reference to the capture in the replacement string: `r'\1'`

Answer (score 4):

[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) replace matched pattern with *replacement* string. `([a-z])` here is also matched, so it gets removed. To avoid this, you can use look ahead syntax:

```
import re
re.sub('-\n(?=[a-z])', '','-\nabc',re.M)
# 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the string to be replaced:

`re.sub('-\n', '','-\nabc')`

will return just the abc

[image]